# Python requests - prevent timeouts or 500 errors

Tags: python, api, python-requests, github-api

I’m writing a python script to access GitHub’s API to send out thousands of requests to get information across the GitHub instance. After some time of running, the script fails due to a 500 error.

The Debug error looks like this:

```
DEBUG:https://github.com/:443 “GET api/v3/repos/<ORG>/<REPO>/teams HTTP/1.1” 500 0
```

This is causing the response to hold an empty json response and the exception caught is:

```
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I’m using requests.get for the api request. Since I am making so many requests, should I be using something different to requests/requests.get or should I be doing something to prevent the server error?

Comment: Is it possible that github has some throttling configuration disallowing you to make such a huge amount of requests in a short span of time?

Comment: Why would you try to get a JSON payload (or indeed any payload) when the HTTP status is not 200? Also, as @Shinratensei has said, you're almost being throttled. If you would normally expect a good response and you're getting a 500, you could try introducing a delay and then re-trying